# Filter Dask Dataframe on categorical column?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Say I have a large dask dataframe of fruit.  I have thousands of rows but only about 30 unique fruit names, so I make that column a category:

```
df['fruit_name'] = df.fruit_name.astype('category')
```

Now that this is a category, can I no longer filter it?  For instance,

```
df_kiwi = df[df['fruit_name'] == 'kiwi']
```

will return TypeError("invalid type comparison")

If I try to create a "dummy" dataframe and merge against that, I get a ValueError: "You are trying to merge on int8 and category columns..."

```
df_dummy = pd.DataFrame(data={'fruit_name': 'kiwi'}, index=range(1))
df_dummy['fruit_name'] = df_dummy.fruit_name.astype('category')

df_new = df.merge(df_dummy, how="inner", on="fruit_name")
```

Do I lose certain merge and filter functionality on a categorical column, or am I just doing this wrong (I am still extremely new to dask and pandas).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example showing this working well:

```
In [1]: import dask

In [2]: df = dask.datasets.timeseries()

In [3]: df.head()
Out[3]: 
                       id      name         x         y
timestamp                                              
2000-01-01 00:00:00   978    Hannah  0.194721  0.518782
2000-01-01 00:00:01   973   Michael -0.894162 -0.454409
2000-01-01 00:00:02  1043       Bob  0.829046 -0.585921
2000-01-01 00:00:03  1027     Edith -0.109735  0.563914
2000-01-01 00:00:04   970  Patricia -0.621248 -0.655324

In [4]: df['name'] = df.name.astype('category')

In [5]: df[df.name == 'Alice'].head()
Out[5]: 
                       id   name         x         y
timestamp                                           
2000-01-01 00:00:23   997  Alice -0.662165 -0.260169
2000-01-01 00:00:58  1012  Alice -0.840159 -0.036770
2000-01-01 00:01:23   961  Alice  0.831663  0.022570
2000-01-01 00:01:27   987  Alice -0.874289 -0.358708
2000-01-01 00:02:09   984  Alice  0.445238 -0.658470
```

I recommend constructing a [minimal failing example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are correct; I sent the parquet elsewhere with Pyarrow then loaded it back in.  I didn't explicitly define the schema and I think that's where the issue came from.  Thanks!

Comment: As of today I think that PyArrow may not keep categorical information around.  I *think* (though am not sure) that there may be open JIRA issues about this.